# Using .on Click to attach handlers to future <li> click events

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which dynamiclly adds `<li>` elements when `addBTS()` is called. Click handlers are attached to all present and future `<li>` elements using the jQuery .on click event:

```
class Toolbar
  constructor: () ->

    @selected_BTS = undefined
    @bts_dropdown_selecion_clickhandler()

  addBTS: (name) =>
    $('#bts-dropdown').append "<li>#{name}</li>"

  bts_dropdown_selecion_clickhandler: () =>
    $('#bts-dropdown li').on 'click', ->
      console.log $(this).html
      Toolbar.selected_BTS = $(this).html
      $('#bts-display-button').html(@selected_BTS)
```

For somereason the click event does not resister when I click on any of the generated `<li>` elements. Could anyone please help me to explain why this is not working? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding for `on` needs to be bound to a parent element that is there from the time of binding.  Since your binding to `$('#bts-dropdown li')` directly it only will find static li's.  The way `on` should work is as follows:

```
$('#bts-dropdown').on('click', 'li', function()
{
});
```

But if #bts-dropdown is even assumed to change, then take the safe route of:

```
$(document).on('click', '#bts-dropdown li', function()
{
});
```

What that syntax looks like in coffee script (that's what I assume this is?  Might want to edit your tags so it hits the correct audience), I'm not sure.  But this should get you where you need to be once you figure out how to put it in the correct syntax.  If someone else offers a more correct solution in the proper syntax, feel free to mark it as the correct answer.  Just trying to help.

My guess is:

```
$('#bts-dropdown').on 'click', 'li', ->
```

Edit: To address your new issue of what is being logged to the console, when calling the method `html` you need `()`.  Without it, it accesses the property (in this case a function) called `html` then calls `toString` on it.  What you're seeing is the jQuery `html` function body.

```
console.log $(this).html()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be changing your question each time something is answered then something new breaks.  They should be separate issues.  This makes accurately answering your question impossible.  The only thing I can point you to at this point is that you're setting a property called `Toolbar.selected_BTS` but you're outputting `@selected_BTS`.  Your set should probably be `@selected_BTS = $(this).html()` but again I don't know coffee script.  This has now morphed from the original two questions into something new.  If my answers helped solve the original problems please accept it and ask a new Q